# How to achieve start sync and stop sync using post method in android?

Tags: android

I want to upload array of pictures , array of videos to server which I want do in synchronization. I want to manage this sync as start whenever i needed and stop it whenever i don't want or WiFi or net connection is disconnected.

Please help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough. I hope this will serve your purpose

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html